Explicit graphical calculus representation of Choi-Jamiolowski isomorphism?
Crossposted from the Quantum Computing SE:
I've been reading the following lecture notes from A. Mueller-Hermes' Quantum Information Theory course (Lecture 4: Equivalence between open and closed quantum systems) in which two isomorphisms are defined:

vectorization: $\text{vec}:B(H_A,H_B)\to H_A\otimes H_B$ and
the Choi-Jamiolowski isomorphism: $C:B(B(H_A), B(H_B )) \to B(H_A \otimes H_B )$
where $H_A, H_B$ are Hilbert spaces and $B(H)$ is the space of bounded linear operators on the Hilbert space $H.$

The graphical representation for $\text{vec}(A)$ is drawn on page 4, and reproduced here for convenience:

I think I understand it, but I'm struggling to draw a similarly intuitive picture of $C(L)$ for $L\in B(B(H_A), B(H_B))$
I'm aware that they are effectively equivalent, but I'd like to draw a diagram that would let me see immediately e.g. the identity listed as Lemma 1.3: $C(L) = (id_A\otimes L) (\omega_{d_A})$  (for $\omega_{d_A}$ the $d_A$ dimensional maximally mixed density matrix)
as well as similar such calculations.
Put simply, if $\text{vec}(A)$ is given by the picture above, what is $C(L)?$

Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

N.B: I've drawn the diagrams with the convention of time going 'up' the page, as opposed to the usual convention (in the QC literature) of time going from left to right, across the page. Sorry; this is just what I am used to. You can just rotate them all by 90 degrees clockwise, if you want to recover the QC convention.
To start with, note that diagrammatically the (unnormalised) maximally entangled state $|\Omega_d\rangle$ literally just looks like an identity wire that has been 'bent' around into a u-shape, such that the dual-space (the bras) become a regular vector space (kets). The fact you have followed the vectorisation example okay suggests this is already clear to you, so I'm just restating it here for completeness. The corresponding density matrix, $\omega_d = |\Omega_d\rangle\langle\Omega_d|$, then just looks like two of these u-shapes stacked on top of each other; one for the dual-space $\langle\Omega_d|$ (which is flipped the other way around to 'dualise' it; technically we are taking the dagger of $|\Omega_d\rangle$, but as it is a real-valued vector this just corresponds to transposition, which diagrammatically just requires flipping it upside down) and one for the normal vector space $|\Omega_d\rangle$.

Okay, so now we have some superoperator $L$, which acts on the space of bounded operators on $\mathbb{C}^{d_A}$. This could simply be some unitary conjugation, $L(\rho) = U\rho U^{\dagger}$ for some $d_A$ by $d_A$ unitary $U$. In this case, the isomorphism would just look like so,

where I have explicitly labelled all the parts in the diagram. Acting with $L$ on one of half of $\omega_d$ effectively 'bends' the input legs of $U$ and $U^{\dagger}$ round, turning the bras of $U$ into kets and the kets of $U^{\dagger}$ into bras. Acting with $\textrm{id}_A$ on the other half of $\omega_{d_A}$ is there just to pad things out and ensure you can properly define some $C_L$ via this action on $\omega_{d_A}$.
More generally, if say $L$ is some quantum channel and you can express it via a decomposition into Kraus operators, $L(\rho) = \sum_K K\rho K^{\dagger}$, the isomorphism would look (pretty much identically) like so:

I'm not bothering to label $\omega_{d_A}$ and $\textrm{id}_A$ this time; hopefully it is clear that the isomorphism can really just be thought of as a bending of the wires (at least this is how I think of it, and it sounds like you are thinking along these lines too).
In my field of study - random unitary and dual-unitary circuits, for studying many-body physics - this kind of folding/vectorisation operation that the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism embodies has become very popular, in the form of something known as the 'folded' picture. See "Operator Entanglement in Local Quantum Circuits I: Chaotic Dual-Unitary Circuits", Bruno Bertini, Pavel Kos, Tomaž Prosen, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.07407 (Section 2.1, specifically) for a good discussion of this.
A thing I like about the folded picture is the compactified notation commonly used for thinking about the folded tensors, that makes things a lot neater. Consider, for instance, vectorising $\omega_d$. In the folded notation, we represent this like so:

When we fold in the first step, we create two copies of $\mathbb{C}^{d}$ on each side of the $A|B$ partition. This is just the vectorisation operation, exactly as characterised in the notes you linked. We then perform a (in some senses purely aesthetic) second step of 'squishing' these two copies together into one single wire - a $d^2$ dim. Hilbert space, $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$. You might worry that we have lost track of the tensor product structure of this space upon performing this squishing, and that we might make errors when performing future contractions, but it actually doesn't really matter - as long as we fold and squish all our tensors in a consistent way, all subsequent operations in this new folded and squished picture should respect the hidden tensor product structure just fine. We can always also unsquish or unfold pretty easily, if we want to check things.
In this new folded picture, the isomorphism looks even more straightforward. Defining some operator $\mathbb{L}$, which is the folded version of $L$ and now simply an operator on our squished wire $\mathbb{C}^{d^2}$ (which has that hidden tensor product structure - $\mathbb{C}^{d^2} = \mathbb{C}^{d} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{d}$ - that, as long as we are careful, we no longer need to worry about or draw), rather than a super operator on $\mathcal{B}({\mathbb{C}^d})$, the isomorphism can be represented diagrammatically as follows:

Note that the $K^{\dagger}$ Kraus operators get transposed when you fold them over, and so become $K^* = (K^{\dagger})^T$.
This picture I think clearly shows what is going on with the isomorphism; it now looks identical to the diagram you gave for vectorisation (we just had to utilise the folded picture - which is itself one layer of vectorisation - to really show this).
There are maybe some subtleties to the CJ-isomorphism (see this blog post https://mattleifer.info/2011/08/01/the-choi-jamiolkowski-isomorphism-youre-doing-it-wrong/, and ensuing responses https://mateusaraujo.info/2020/06/10/the-choi-jamiolkowski-isomorphism-youre-doing-it-right/), but for most purposes I think you're totally okay to just think about it diagrammatically as a simple bending of wires, as above.
